# .NET NotifyIcon randomly disappearing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I have a WPF application that consists of a long running main window.  In the `MainWindow` constructor I define a Notify icon:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon;

public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu notifyMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
   System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem notifyMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
   notifyMenuItem.Text = "Exit MainWindow";
   notifyMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(notifyMenuItem_Click);
   notifyMenu.MenuItems.Add(notifyMenuItem);
   notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
   notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "MainWindow has been minimized. Click the tray icon to show.";
   notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "MainWindow";
   notifyIcon.Text = "MainWindow";
   notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("some.ico");
   notifyIcon.Visible = true;
   notifyIcon.Click += new EventHandler(notifyIcon_Click);
   notifyIcon.ContextMenu = notifyMenu;
}
```

This is all good and well, except that sometimes the `NotifyIcon` simply disappears from the tray.  Absolutely nowhere in the code is `notifyIcon.Visible = false;` set as the `NotifyIcon` should also be visible.  My application (by requirement) does not show up in the taskbar and uses a single instance manager (if another instance starts up, the newer instance is required to abort immediately).  So this leads to a situation where the application was minimized to the tray, the NotifyIcon disappears and the user things the application is not running (it is) and they cannot start a new one (single instance mechanism).

I've seen some SO posts on this matter but they seem to blame the NotifyIcon being instantiated somewhere other than the main windows, which does not apply to my case.  Are there other reasons for flaky NotifyIcon behavior, as well as remedies?

Comment: Was it maybe just moved to the overflow area by Windows? Try clicking the little arrow to the left of the notification area.

Comment: @Јοеу Unfortunately no it doesn't go there.  To 100% guarantee I have for this application configured the `NotifyIcon` to _always_ be visible.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads? Which thread is calling the constructor to MainWindow? Which thread is doing Application.Run()?

Comment: @antiduh That comment made me think in another direction and solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the OS, doesn't the user specify whether notify icons remain visible or only report status messages?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the author has stated that he solved the problem but did not post an answer explaining what he did to solve it.

Comment: I had the same issue in a WinForms application that uses Reactive Extensions (Rx) and the comment about threading reminded me to check, if my subscriptions that modify GUI-Controls had ".ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)". After fixing that, the problem seems to have gone away.